# Creating a custom Close Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, user-interface

I need to implement a custom window decorator where a **Close** button will behave exactly as the close or <kbd>x</kbd> button on all Windows applications.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply call the `close()` function from your button:

WPF:

```
<Button Name="CloseButton" Content="x" Click="CloseButton_Click" />
```

code-behind:

```
private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

Comment: I tried command="close" and nothing happens. Is there something else that needs to be done to get command="close" to actually close the window?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use MVVM architecture, then you can pass the name of your window as a Command Parameter and in the Command you can close the window.

The code would be something like this:

```
Button Command="{Binding MainCloseButtonCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}"

private void performMainCloseButtonCommand(object Parameter)
{
    Window objWindow  = Parameter as Window;
    objWindow.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Button which will close the dialog `Window`, you can add for him `IsCancel` property:

```
<Button Name="CloseButton"
        IsCancel="True" ... />
```

This means the following [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.iscancel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When you set the `IsCancel` property of a Button to true, you create a Button that is registered with the AccessKeyManager. *The button is then activated when a user presses the ESC key*.

Now, if you click on this Button, or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> then dialog `Window` is closing, but it does not work for the normal `MainWindow`.

To close the `MainWindow`, you can simply add a Click handler which has already been shown. But if you want a more elegant solution that would satisfy the MVVM style you can add the following *attached* behavior:

```
public static class ButtonBehavior
{
    #region Private Section

    private static Window MainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;

    #endregion

    #region IsCloseProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCloseProperty;

    public static void SetIsClose(DependencyObject DepObject, bool value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(IsCloseProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsClose(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (bool)DepObject.GetValue(IsCloseProperty);
    }

    static ButtonBehavior()
    {
        IsCloseProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsClose",
                                                              typeof(bool),
                                                              typeof(ButtonBehavior),
                                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsCloseTurn));
    }

    #endregion

    private static void IsCloseTurn(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
        {
            if (MainWindow != null)
                MainWindow.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);

            var button = sender as Button;

            if (button != null)
                button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
        }
    }

    private static void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow.Close();
    }

    private static void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            MainWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

And in `Window` use like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProjectNamespace.MainWindow" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace">

    <Button Name="CloseButton"
            local:ButtonBehavior.IsClose="True" ... />
```

Now the `MainWindow` can be closed by clicking on the Button or pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and it all happens independent from `View` (UI).

Answer (score 1):

If you add a button to your current view lets say from code behind:

```
var closeButton = new Button();
closeButton.Click += closeButton_Click;

// Add the button to the window
Content = closeButton;
```

Then you can respond to the event and just call `Close()` like this:

```
void closeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```

What this basicly does is that it adds a button to your `Window` / `UserControl` and when you press it, it will close the Window.

If you do it from `XAML` it could look like this:

`<Button Name="closeButton" Click="closeButton_Click" />`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is this:

```
<Window Name = "Chrome">
   .
   .
  <Button Name="closeButton" onClick="terminateApplication"/>
   .
</Window>
```

and in the CS file,

```
private void terminateApplication(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Chrome.Close();
}
```

Comment: What do I not understand about this? If you are within the code-behind of the window, you don't need to call it by name. So your code is basically a longer version of the code in the other answers. I'm afraid your answer is risking a downvote.

Comment: this was a more 'generalized' answer....

also, i was writing this when 2 more answers poured in... :D

Answer (score 0):

Use close button with viewmodel. View model IS NOT DEPEND on gui.

```
namespace YourLibrary.ComponentModel
{
   /// <summary>
  /// Defines Close method. Use for window, file stream,.... 
  /// </summary>
  public interface IClosable
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// Close of instance (window, file stream,... etc).
      /// </summary>
      void Close();
  }
```

}

MyWindow.xaml

```
  <Window  ...
       x:Name="ThisInstance"   
       ...
   >


   <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ThisInstance}">
```

MyWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window, YourLibrary.ComponentModel.IClosable
{
 ....
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
  ICommand buttonCommand;
  /// <summary>
  /// Command for Button.
  /// Default action is close the window.  
  /// Close window via retyping parameter as <see cref="IClosable"/> 
  /// </summary>
  public ICommand ButtonCommand => buttonCommand ?? (buttonCommand=new RelayCommand(ButtonCommandExecute));
  void ButtonCommandExecute (object obj) 
  {
      var myWindow = (IClosable)obj;
      myWindow.Close();
  };
```

TESTING, USE VIEWMODEL IN CONSOLE

```
 class Program
 {
    public class ConsoleWindow : YourLibrary.ComponentModel.IClosable
    {
        public void Close()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Closing area...");
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        program.DoMain(args);
    }

    public void DoMain(string[] args)
    {
        var consoleWindow = new ConsoleWindow();
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel()
        viewModel.ButtonCommand.Execute(consoleWindow);
    }
 }
```